# Removing unnecessary exec statements for speed improvement

Tags: python, refactoring, python-exec

I am trying to refactor some python code i have at my disposal. The developer is using exec statement a lot but for very simple tasks like

```
temp = dict(....)
exec("x_dct=" + temp)

items = x_dct.items()
```

My most important question is do we need exec for those simple variable assignments? Does it cost to use exec for those simple assignments? Appart for code not looking good is there any other reason we shouldn't use exec for this kind of purpose?

Comment: As per many programmers advise `exec` should only be used when there is no other way to do. Since you are doing only normal variable assignments and stuffs you could remove it .

Comment: Whoever is doing stuff like that should have their head examined.

Comment: So (I think) what the developer meant to do was `x_dct = temp.copy()`.

Comment: I think that the code that you have at your disposal should be disposed of.

Comment: Yes..but does it affect speed or anything rather than looks of the code?